# shell script replace and add next line with special characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying replace a line with another line and add new line below that using shell script. My file content looks like below. I want to replace `export PATH` with `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-ibm-1.8.0.2.10-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64
export PATH JAVA_HOME`

before:

```
export PATH
```

It should be after:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-ibm-1.8.0.2.10-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64

export PATH JAVA_HOME
```

That means, it has to replace replace export PATH with these two lines.

Please help me how can I do with sed or shell script

Thanks,
Kumar.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277938/13792

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e 's#^export PATH$#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-ibm-1.8.0.2.10-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64\n\nexport PATH JAVA_HOME#' <yourfile.txt
```

This is just a single **s**ubstitute command in sed.

Some notes:

- The `#` is used after **s** instead of the usual `/` to avoid having to quote all slashes in the path. Otherwise you have to quote each `/` in the path this way: `/`. ow you only have to quote `#`.
- The escape sequence `\n` insert a newline.
- Add the `-i` parameter to sed if you want to actually update the file. The code above only prints the new file to *stdout*.
- The regex is *anchored* (`^...$`) so that it matches the whole line and not just a part of it.